# Send Email from Custom Button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, email-template

I have a Visualforce page and I would like to create a custom button that sends an email template to the user's Manager (via the Manager field on the user record) and VP (a custom lookup field on my custom object).  I tried to do this via a URL hack, but all that does is pull up the pre-populated template.  I want the email to be sent without the user even seeing the template.  Is this possible to do right in the VF page without a controller, perhaps with Javascript?  And if so, is there any code examples?

Current Button:

```
<a
role="button"
class="btn" 
style="text-decoration:none;background:#FFFF00;"
href = "/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&
        p3_lkid={!DS.Id}&
        retURL=%2F{!DS.Id}&
        p5={!$User.Email}&
        p24={!$User.Manager_Email__c},{!DS.BD_Manager__r.email}&
        template_id=00X37000000kzHl",
        target = "_self">
<b>Manager Review</b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do with  Salesforce AJAX Toolkit. You can write something like this in your JavaScript. You can update the `SendMail` function with all the required parametes and call from the onclick action of the button.

```
<apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SendMail() {
            try {
                sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
                var message = new sforce.SingleEmailMessage();
                message.replyTo = "xxxx@gmail.com";
                message.targetObjectId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                message.templateId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                message.saveAsActivity = false;
                message.plainTextBody = "this test went through ajax";
                var result = sforce.connection.sendEmail([message]);
                if(result[0].success == 'true') {
                    alert("Mail sent successfully");
                } else {
                    alert("I had a booboo.");
                }
            }catch(e) { 
                alert("Error Occurred: \n\n" + (e.message||e));
            }
        }
  </script>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would the call then from my <a> tag just be "OnClick = "SendMail""?

Comment: Yes, you can call the method in the OnClick event of the anchor.

Comment: I tried that, but nothing happens.  Here's my anchor:

'<a  role="button"
            class="btn" 
            style="text-decoration:none;background:#FFFF00;"
            OnClick = "SendMail" 
            target = "_self">
            <b>Manager Review</b>
</a>'

Comment: Please check the browser console for any error.

Comment: No errors are showing in the console.  It just seems to be doing nothing.